# What Stack Exchange site(s) is (are) appropriate for recommendations of website-building platforms allowing server-side access?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, web-hosting

I've come to the point where I need my Squarespace [website](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org) to do more than the Squarespace platform is designed to do, namely provide server-side access to [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Squarespace permits no server-side access whatsoever even from within its "Developer Platform."

The critical [page](https://familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/class-schedule-2019/) on the site retrieves data stored on the AWS [DynamoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_DynamoDB) servers and dynamically populates a table on the page. I need secure, credentialed access to the servers, thus requiring server-side Node.js and Ajax functionality. I need a site-builder because I'm not competent to build one and my non-profit group hasn't the money to hire a professional. Those twin requirements constrain the set of appropriate site hosts.

It seems that I need to migrate the site to some other website-building platform similar to Squarespace but that allows server-side access.

I would like recommendations for quality website-building platforms similar to Squarespace but that provide server-side access to Node.js and Ajax functionality.

I would like to solicit recommendations from knowledgeable people for three to five sights ranked from most to least preferred with reasons.

I would also like to know if you believe that more information about my site and its requirements is needed for a reader to respond effectively.

What Stack Exchange site(s) is (are) appropriate for this specific question?

Do you believe that more information will be needed? What?

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your thought, but no. That site is for questions to webmasters about site operations. My question is not about how the site operates (or should operate), but rather where to host it given the twin requirements of server-side access and a web-building platform like Squarespace. Please share the question if you think of someone who might answer it. Thanks again.

Comment: While they do allow questions on the [looking-for-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-hosting) tag a list of [recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) (without a *shortlist*) is generally off-topic on most sites regardless of the subject matter.

Comment: ["All future questions \[on Webmasters.SE\] pertaining to finding web hosting should be closed as a duplicate of this question."](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/20838/113491)

Answer (score 2):

To the extent you're asking for someone to recommend a software platform rather than a hosting service, this question would be on-topic at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Please make sure to carefully read over [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/70127) before posting to ensure that your question is on-topic.  It sounds like you're looking for a *software platform* rather than a *service*, so I think you'd be good, but you should still read it over.  You'll probably also want to have a look at [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/70127)

This question would *not*, as is suggested in the comments, be on-topic at Webmasters.SE, which [forbids](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions asking for "[r]ecommendations for sites and resources," including tools.  They also have a [canonical question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/20838/113491) that states that "[a]ll future questions [on Webmasters.SE] pertaining to finding web hosting should be closed as a duplicate of this question."

Comment: Software Recommendations.SE appears inappropriate. I agree that Webmasters.SE is inappropriate. I don't need software advice, just the identity of some web-building sites like Squarespace but that allow server-side access for developers, unlike Squarespace. If I can just be pointed in the right direction, I'll do the rest. Perhaps there is no such SE site. I'd like to know.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/686/70127), your question seems more like the example on-topic question.  it seems that your question is asking for a software platform with certain features.